# How to set TTL in cache storage of browser?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am building my website in progressive web app. So for caching I am using cache storage as well as index DB. IS there any way to set TTL of cache storage as well as index DB?. Do we have to delete the cache manually or will it occur automatically.?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage the cache yourself.

You can use tools like [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/googlechrome/sw-toolbox) to help manage expiration and number of cache entries.

I'm not sure what you could use for indexDB.